# Как разрешить выполнение скрипта только через cron?

Tags: php, cron

К примеру есть скрипт, расположенный по адресу https://site.ru/cron/test.php

Как запретить прямой переход по ссылке, в общем чтобы только cron мог выполнять его?

Comment: просто передавать get параметр(при запуске кроном) и проверять его на стороне скрипта недостаточно?

Comment: @Sleeeper, если честно, то как-то неправильно чтоли это. Хотелось бы полностью сделать так, чтобы вручную никак скрипт не выполнить было.

Comment: ну тогда надо перекладывать скрипт в более "системный" каталог и запускать напрямую через php по типу: php /var/www/......./files/test.php

Comment: А правда, если скрипт не должен быть доступен как часть сайта, то _зачем класть его в подкаталог сайта_?

Comment: @VladD, мне интересно как сделать так, чтобы вручную не перейти :) Хотя у меня есть мысль, это проверить, существует ли $_SERVER или нет. При выполнении через крон как-раз таки вроде он отстутствует.

Comment: *чтобы вручную никак скрипт не выполнить было* — «из cron-а» — это ровно точто так же «вручную».

Comment: Ответы просто жесть :) Кладите скрипт в директорию, которая к сайту не относится и всё. Запрет на выполнение именно "руками" не нужен. Кого боитесь? Себя? А другие к вам на сервер и не должны попадать. В любом случае, программно это решаться не должно. Если вы "закодили" запрет на выполнение, то никто не мешает кому-то другому ваш скрипт поправить. В общем, положите скрипт вне директории сайта и проставьте права на этот файл средствами ОС.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для проверки того, что скрипт запущен из командной строки я использую такую функцию:

```
function isCommandLine() {
   return defined('STDIN');
}
```

Скорее всего она не будет работать если PHP-скрипт запускается как CGI, но такое в наше время редкость.

Comment: огромное спасибо. Выручили!

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать использовать функцию `php_sapi_name()` или константу `PHP_SAPI`.
[Ссылка](http://php.net/manual/ru/features.commandline.introduction.php)

В моем случае, при обращении к скрипту из браузера, `PHP_SAPI` принимает значение `fpm-fcgi`. Из консоли `cgi`

Answer (score 1):

в комментариях рекомендуют какие-нибудь уникальные параметры, но, действительно, их можно передать и в *http-запросе*.

если задача состоит в том, чтобы выполянять скрипт только «руками» (`cron` тоже попадает в эту категорию), а не через *http-сервер*, то логично использовать переменные окружения.

команду вызова «вручную» (`cron`, напомню, входит в эту категорию) можно предварить присвоением какого-нибудь значения переменной с уникальным именем, которое вряд ли сгенерирует *http-сервер*. примерно так:

```
 unik_imja=1 /путь/к/скрипту.php параметры скрипта
```

ну а в скрипте проверить её (переменной окружения) наличие с помощью `getenv`:

```
$ unik_imja=1 php -r 'print "unik_imja=" . getenv("unik_imja") . "\n";'
unik_imja=1
$ php -r 'print "unik_imja=" . getenv("unik_imja") . "\n";'
unik_imja=
```

---

подразумевается, что проблема с переменными окружения, которую решает [safe_mode](http://php.net/manual/ro/features.safe-mode.php), вам известна и неактуальна.