# как запустить my sql php через cron?

Tags: php, mysql, cron, crontab

я так понимаю мне нужно 
сделать отдельный файл  file.php 
вставить в него

```
<?php
$this->db->query("DELETE FROM `paygo` WHERE created_date < ".( time()-60*2 )); // через 30 минут
?>
```

потом 
cсылку на это фал вставить в крон

/home/логинхостинга/сайт.домен/www/file.php

вот так или я делаю что то не так, 
а как допустим защитить этот файл

Comment: возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как разрешить выполнение скрипта только через cron?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/436966/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-cron) (в частности — [этот ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/436982/178576)).

Comment: @alexanderbarakin тут вопрос состоит правильно я сделал запрос для крона? а не только вы прочитали последнею букву и сразу начали коментировать

Comment: Какой смысл его защищать? Вам необходимо что бы он строго раз в пол часа выполнялся, если да, тогда вам действительно нужно его защищать в противном случае защита не имеет ни какого смысла. Т.к. Судя по коду вы просто подчищаете таблицу...

Comment: @kursof, в моём ответе, на который я ссылаюсь, приведён пример, вполне схожий с тем, что написано в вашем вопросе.

Comment: @fens код очищает записи старше 30 дней,

Comment: @kursof судя по коду он очищает записи которые старше 2 минут.

Comment: @fens в данный момент да

Comment: Ну так и дёргайте этот файл откуда угодно... От того что он чаще выполниться хуже никому не будет. А в качестве меры защиты можно поставить права на файл 555

Comment: А не проще, скажем, не класть file.php в www, а положить, например, чуть выше?

Comment: @cronfy www директива самого сайта, так он только работает. когда все файлы лежат в www

Comment: Это понятно, но вам-то не сайт надо запустить, а консольный скрипт. Пробовали вытащить его из www, подправить пути в require и запустить в консоли?

Comment: @cronfy да какая там консоль) все методом тыка клаца и народного метода, идея не плохая в принципе можно будет по пробовать, но щас не отправляет запрос в бд ( думаю как решить

Comment: Так вы бы скинули полный код скрипта, а то одна строчка ничего не говорит, почему не работает

Answer (score 0):

1. Способ выше (см ссылку). Часто используется в framework например с в CodeIgniter
2. Скрипты в отдельной папке с закрытым доступом всем через htaccess
   /usr/bin/php -f /home/логинхостинга/сайт.домен/www/cron/file.php >/dev/null
3. Просто отдельные скрипты вне зоны видимости хоста

   /usr/bin/php -f /home/логинхостинга/cron/file.php >/dev/null