# Как защитить CRON скрипты

Tags: php, cron

Ребята нужно сделать что бы только CronJob мог использовать файлы в папке CRON, больше никто, как осуществить?

Comment: рут всегда сможет, мне кажется, не?

Comment: В файле установите защиту от внешнего запроса, т.е чтобы не смогли напрямую обратиться к файлу.

Comment: Либо файл располагаете так, чтобы он вне www папки.

Comment: if (PHP_SAPI !== 'cli') {
    die('Not allowed');
}

Comment: @lampa Спасибо помогло)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как разрешить выполнение скрипта только через cron?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/436966/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-cron)